# Replace values in dataframe based on multiple rows from other dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 data frames. The first data frame (say df1) has multiple rows and columns. The second and third data frames (say df2 and df3) have only one row and a subset of columns from df1. The column names in df2 and df3 are same. So what I want to do is to compare each row in df1 with the single row in df2 and df3. If the value of a cell from df1 matches with the cell content of df2, replace the value of the cell in df1 with 1 and if the value of the cell from df1 matches with df3, replace the value of the cell in df1 with 2 and if the cell content of df2 doesn't match with either df2 or df3, replace the value of the cell in df1 with -. I wrote a loop to do this but it is slow. I would like to know if there is any optimized way to do this. Thank you.

Here are the example data frames and the expected output:

```
df1
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11 c12
 q  w   e   r   t   y   q   w   e   r   t   y
 q  e   r   t   y   q   e   r   e   r   t   y
 w  e   r   t   y   t   q   w   e   r   w   t

df2
                c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11 c12
                t   y   q   w   e   t   w   t

df3             
                c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11 c12
                y   q   q   t   e   r   t   t

Expected output:                
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11 c12
q   w   e   r   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   -
q   e   r   t   2   2   -   -   1   2   2   -
w   e   r   t   2   -   1   1   1   2   1   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find common columns using `intersect`. Repeat rows of `df2` and `df3` and compare them with `df1` and replace the matching values in `df1` by 1 and that of `df2` by 2 and replace all other by `"-"`.

```
cols <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df1[cols][df1[cols] == df2[rep(seq_len(nrow(df2)), nrow(df1)), ]] <- 1
df1[cols][df1[cols] == df3[rep(seq_len(nrow(df3)), nrow(df1)), ]] <- 2
df1[cols][(df1[cols] != 1) & (df1[cols] != 2)] <- "-"


df1
#  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12
#1  q  w  e  r  1  1  1  1  1   2   2   -
#2  q  e  r  t  2  2  -  -  1   2   2   -
#3  w  e  r  t  2  -  1  1  1   2   1   1
```

---

Based on comments if we want to fill the remaining values in `df1` which is not present in `df2` and `df3`, we can find out the mismatched indices and use `paste0` to paste values together.

```
temp_df2 <- df2[rep(seq_len(nrow(df2)), nrow(df1)), ]
temp_df3 <- df3[rep(seq_len(nrow(df2)), nrow(df1)), ]
df1[cols][df1[cols] == temp_df2] <- 1
df1[cols][df1[cols] == temp_df3] <- 2
inds <- (df1[cols] != 1) & (df1[cols] != 2)
df1[cols][inds] <- paste0(df1[cols][inds], temp_df2[inds], temp_df3[inds])

df1
#  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5  c6  c7  c8 c9 c10 c11 c12
#1  q  w  e  r  1   1   1   1  1   2   2 ytt
#2  q  e  r  t  2   2 eqq rwt  1   2   2 ytt
#3  w  e  r  t  2 tyq   1   1  1   2   1   1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. This solved the problem. I just have another question -  Instead of replacing the cells without 1 or 2 with "-", Is it possible to apply a function. For example, in the output, instead of "-", just fill them with the concatenated string of value from df1, df2 and df3?

Comment: @Victor What do you mean by concatenated values? Can you explain using an example? So `-` in `c6` would be replaced by ?

Comment: The "-" in c6 would be replaced by tyq, y and q from c6 of df2 and df3, t from 3rd row of c6 of df1.

Answer (score 0):

We can create couple of logical matrix by replicating the rows of 'df2' and 'df3' while selecting only the columns of df1 that are the same from 'df2' or 'df3', then we assgn the values in a single step by logical comparison

```
i1 <- df1[names(df2)] == df2[rep(1, nrow(df1)),]
i2 <- df1[names(df3)] == df3[rep(1, nrow(df1)),]
df1[names(df3)] <- ((!i1 & i2) + 1) * NA^(!i1 & !i2)
df1
#   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12
#1  q  w  e  r  1  1  1  1  1   2   2  NA
#2  q  e  r  t  2  2 NA NA  1   2   2  NA
#3  w  e  r  t  2 NA  1  1  1   2   1   1
```

It may be better to have `NA` instead of `-` as `-` can change the column type from `numeric` to `character`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(c1 = c("q", "q", "w"), c2 = c("w", "e", "e"), 
    c3 = c("e", "r", "r"), c4 = c("r", "t", "t"), c5 = c("t", 
    "y", "y"), c6 = c("y", "q", "t"), c7 = c("q", "e", "q"), 
    c8 = c("w", "r", "w"), c9 = c("e", "e", "e"), c10 = c("r", 
    "r", "r"), c11 = c("t", "t", "w"), c12 = c("y", "y", "t")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(c5 = "t", c6 = "y", c7 = "q", c8 = "w", c9 = "e", 
    c10 = "t", c11 = "w", c12 = "t"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

df3 <- structure(list(c5 = "y", c6 = "q", c7 = "q", c8 = "t", c9 = "e", 
    c10 = "r", c11 = "t", c12 = "t"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I'm sure the output of this is nearly the same as the one I asked. The output can also be a character. I specified "-" because there are already missing values in the original data and I don't want to fill the cells with different values as missing. I just have another question - Instead of replacing the cells with NA, Is it possible to apply a function. For example, in the output, instead of NA, just fill them with the concatenated string of value from df1, df2 and df3?

Comment: @Victor That is an easy fix.  But I also explained why it sshouldn't be there